# Question about total energy of ejected electrons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, electrons, potential-energy, photoelectric-effect

We know total energy of a body is the sum of total kinetic energy + potential energy.

What I learned from atomic electromagnetic theory of light is that kinetic energy of ejected electrons = Hf - W(Work function ).

My question is , then what about the electrostatic potential energy which happened when the electron got separated  from the atom? Why didn’t we consider it?

I checked this doubt of mine a lot online. People only wrote about kinetic energy with no mention of potential energy.

Comment: @John Rennie Can you please help here sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what about the electrostatic potential energy which happened when the electron got separated from the atom?

That's what the work function is.

If you consider a single atom then to eject an electron you have to supply an energy equal to the energy of the highest energy electron. For example in a hydrogen atom the highest electron energy is $-13.6$ eV so you have to supply an energy of $13.6$ eV to eject the electron. So if you use a photon to ionise the hydrogen atom the kinetic energy of the ejected electron will be:

$$ T = h\nu - 13.6~\textrm{eV} $$

In solids the atomic energy levels merge together to form bands. Electrons in a band are in effect bound to the whole array of the atoms in the crystal rather to a single atom. Within a band we still have a highest energy electron, and this energy is called the [Fermi level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_level). To eject an electron from the solid you have to supply an energy equal to the Fermi level, and this energy is what we call the work function (denoted by $\phi$). So the kinetic energy of the ejected electron is:

$$ T = h\nu - \phi $$

Comment: Oh right.I have one more question that does this mean that work function is the energy required to remove an electron or energy that it possessed (Potential energy )when it got out of the metal surface or body ?

Comment: @user282657 yes

Comment: Also electron is present at many different points in a metal surface.So how come if let us say I put a light on it form one end.Does that

Comment: Mean that electron only form the surface area comes out , but not inside the metal or the other end of metal ?

Comment: Light is strongly absorbed in metals so it penetrates only a short distance into the metal. That means the photoelectrons come from the region near to the surface.

Comment: Oh.Amazing.Thank you very much